# to display the exception soap fault xml sent by the client in mule

Tags: mule, soap-client, mule-studio

i have a mule service in which it contains a proxy service and client.When i give request to client it is throwing some exception.while throwing the exception it is sending one soap fault xml in which it contains details tag which  i need to display it in the response.I am using inInterceptor  in soap client to access the fault and the class used is CheckFaultInterceptor.
At present i am able to access only the fault string from soap client.But my requirement is to access the entire soap fault xml.Please help me.
my mule configuration.xml is:

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="SrvcReq_Gtwy.properties" />
      <spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="CreateSRFaultInterceptor" name="CreateSRFaultInterceptor"
        class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor" />
</spring:beans>
<message-properties-transformer name="AddSoapActionHeader"
    overwrite="true" doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="SOAPAction"
        value="&quot;document/http://siebel.com/CustomUI:CreateSR1&quot;" />
</message-properties-transformer>
    <mulexml:namespace-manager
    includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="srv"
        uri="http://bac.com/wsdl/CIPT/20130923/SrvcRqstMsg" />
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="srv1"
        uri="http://bac.com/xsd/CIPT/20130923/SrvcRqstMsg" />
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
    <flow name="CreateSrvcReqFlow" doc:name="CreateSrvcReqFlow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        path="vm:CreateSrvcReq" doc:name="ReceiveMsgForCreateSR" />
    <component
        class="com.bac.gwb.credit.servicerequest.transformers.CreateServiceRequestIntializer"
        doc:name="InitializeVariables" />
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="PojoToGSSReq_grf"
        doc:name="PojoToGSSReq" />
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer
        doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
        message="ArchivedInvoice Message Payload after transformation is #[message.payload]" />
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String" />
        <flow-ref name="CreateSrvcReqGSSInvocation" doc:name="CreateSRInvocation" />
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer
        returnClass="java.lang.String" doc:name="DOM to XML"></mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
    <logger message="GSS - Response MSG #[message.payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
                <byte-array-to-string-transformer
        doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice_Exception_Strategy1">
        <catch-exception-strategy
            when="#[exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException)]"
            doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                <logger message="Exception is - #[exception] " level="INFO"
                    doc:name="Logger" />
                <data-mapper:transform config-ref="pojo_to_json"
                    doc:name="CreateSoapFaultDM">
                    <data-mapper:input-arguments>
                        <data-mapper:input-argument key="CreateSoapFault">#[exception]
                        </data-mapper:input-argument>
                    </data-mapper:input-arguments>
                </data-mapper:transform>
                <byte-array-to-string-transformer
                    doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
            </processor-chain>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                <logger message="Exception is Other - #[exception] " level="INFO"
                    doc:name="Logger" />
                <data-mapper:transform config-ref="createsoapfaultotherdm_grf"
                    doc:name="DataMapper">
                    <data-mapper:input-arguments>
                        <data-mapper:input-argument key="CreateSoapFaultException">#[exception]
                        </data-mapper:input-argument>
                    </data-mapper:input-arguments>
                </data-mapper:transform>
                <byte-array-to-string-transformer
                    doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
            </processor-chain>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
        </flow>

<flow name="CreateSrvcReqGSSInvocation" doc:name="CreateSrvcReqGSSInvocation">
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer
        returnClass="java.lang.String" doc:name="DOM to XML" />
        <logger message="Request to GSS #[message.payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <cxf:proxy-client doc:name="SOAP"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" payload="envelope">
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="CreateSRFaultInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:proxy-client>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
        doc:name="DOM to XML"
    </mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        method="POST" address="${outbound.gss.sr}" transformer-refs="AddSoapActionHeader"
        doc:name="InvokeGSSCreateSR" responseTimeout="${outbound.gss.sr.responseTimeOutInMillisec}" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding interceptors in the `proxy-client` will help in solving this scenario

See the modified flow. This should provide you with the total soap-fault response from the `HTTP Outbound` call.

```
<flow name="CreateSrvcReqGSSInvocation" doc:name="CreateSrvcReqGSSInvocation">
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer
        returnClass="java.lang.String" doc:name="DOM to XML" />
        <logger message="Request to GSS #[message.payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <cxf:proxy-client doc:name="SOAP"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" payload="envelope">            
    </cxf:proxy-client>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
        doc:name="DOM to XML"
    </mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        method="POST" address="${outbound.gss.sr}" transformer-refs="AddSoapActionHeader"
        doc:name="InvokeGSSCreateSR" responseTimeout="${outbound.gss.sr.responseTimeOutInMillisec}" />
</flow>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,I have tried your solution it worked.but soap fault xml is coming in the payload and mule is not recognizing it as fault and sending it in payload to the remaining flow.what can i do to tell mule that it is a soap fault

Comment: SOAP Fault is also a proper kind of response and Mule will not treat it as exception. You can use a CHOICE to check if the Response is a SOAP Fault and then Perform your required action.

Comment: Yes at present i am using choice block and checking through xpath expression whether it is soap fault or not.If it is soap fault xml then i am routing it to display the fault xml otherwise i m showing the correct result.Thank you